# Google Map Marker Drop Animation in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps

[image]     I am using Google Maps in Swift with clustering. Now I want to show the animation on markers (Drop Animation).I have check on Google and find the link show below:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/marker-animations

```
But it's HTML & Javascript code.Now I need to implement same animation in Swift. Please check my code show below:-                           

marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: Double(self.LocalDataStore[i].Latitude)!, longitude: Double(self.LocalDataStore[i].Longitude)!)
marker.title = self.LocalDataStore[i].postTitle
marker.snippet = self.LocalDataStore[i].postContent
marker.appearAnimation = GMSMarkerAnimation.pop
marker.infoWindowAnchor = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.2)
marker.accessibilityLabel = "\(i)"

I have used pop animation also, But now i need drop animation. Can anybody help me.
```

Comment: check this document https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/marker search animation

Comment: use `marker.appearAnimation`

Comment: i have used, but it show only pop, i need drop animation.

Comment: i have edited, please check.